# How to produce the Mathematica DifferentialD symbol?

Tags: math-mode

Mathematica uses a [double-barred italic lowercase "d"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/DifferentialD.html) in order to represent the differential symbol. How can I include this symbol in a (La)Tex document (in math mode)? There are a number of packages that produce blackboard-bold lowercase letters, but all of them add the extra vertical line on the left side of the glyph. A similar thing happens when I XeLaTeX a source file that uses the Unicode character ⅆ (I guess it must be automatically selecting one of those fonts). I want the extra vertical line on the right, like the Mathematica symbol.

Comment: Please, please, don't!

Comment: @egreg Can you elaborate?

Comment: It's a horrible and completely out-of-place symbol. It's nowhere used except in Mathematica. Leave it alone, please.

Comment: The character is `$ⅆ$` or equivalently `$\mitBbbd$`  with `unicode-math`, but the actual style depends on the font and the OpenType versions of the Mathematica fonts are nolt freely available.

Comment: @egreg it is used in some other systems eg (I understand) Word uses it as an _input_ character for differential d then allowing a document level option to display it using a normal upright or normal italic d. (that use isn't so useful in TeX where you can define a macro do delay making the style choice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character is `$ⅆ$` or equivalently `$\mitBbbd$` with unicode-math, but the actual style depends on the font and the OpenType versions of the Mathematica fonts are not freely available.

If however you have the fonts from Mathematica you can (if the licence permits) use that font via usual fontspec methods.

I tried a few fonts that I do have, but they all had a bar on the left of the bowl of the d

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\def\test#1{#1: {\Large\fontspec{#1}\relax[ⅆ]\par}}
\begin{document}

\test{Stix Two Math}
\test{TeX Gyre Bonum Math}
\test{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}
\test{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\test{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
\test{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\test{Segoe UI Symbol}                                                          
\test{Cambria Math}

\end{document}
```